# Swift 2 - Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to call `save` function on my Model class, however even though it works for 1.2, it throws this error in 2.1:

> `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`

```
func save() -> NSError?{
    var error: NSError?
    self.context?.save(error) // Error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
    return error
}
```

Edit:

I converted the code to:

```
func save() -> NSError?{
    do {
        try context!.save()
    } catch let error as NSError? {
        print("error saving core data: \(error)")
    }
}
```

...but now I am receiving:

> `Missing return in a function expected to return 'NSError?'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func save() -> NSError?{
    do {
        if let context = context {
            try context.save()
        }
    } catch let error as NSError? {
        print("error saving core data: \(error)")
        return error
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Ace! Works like charm. Thanks

Comment: Should I use `context?` or `context!`?

Comment: i don't have a glue what the function is doing, but generally try context? first ...

Answer (score 2):

in swift 2.0 the context.save function implementation changed according to the new error handling!

change it to

```
 do{
      try context!.save()
      }catch let error as NSError{
         print("error saving core data: \(error)")
        }
```

Comment: Oh! So I all error handling method is changed that way. Cheers!

Comment: yeah, you can also see it if you just type context.save and wait for the code completion it says "save() throws" that's an idicator that you have to use a do, try, catch block ;)

Comment: I had a problem on Build. Now, I started receiving `Missing return in a function expected to return NSError?` and when I change `NSError` to `NSError?`, same error continues. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this method or the subclass but you could try to use the pointer of your error variable.

`self.context?.save(&error)`

Comment: It is forcing me to delete `&` symbol with error log: `'&' used with non-input argument of type '()'`

Comment: Okay, sorry, @iVentis answer looks promising

Comment: But now I am receiving a different error, please check my edit in the question